# Terminology: how is a piece of a continuous function called?

Tags: terminology, signal-processing

This is a question about terminology. I have a continuous function (in my case it is a signal in time, a spike train). I divide the time axis in intervals of the same or variable duration, to be processed individually. Which term is used to indicate a piece of the original function in a specific time interval?

Names that seem appropriate are: frame, block, interval, fragment, ...

Is there a better, standard term?

Comment: It is a [*restriction*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restriction_(mathematics)) of this (not necessarily continuous) function to that interval.